# Variable from view to model. MVC

Tags: php, mysql

I am a beginner and wrote a web page based on the tutorial [JREAM](https://jream.com/lab) (MVC). 
I've encountered a problem in displaying articles.
How can I send a variable **$from** (index.php) from the controller to the model?
Of course, I can connect to the database in the index.php but whether that is good?

index.php

```
    $limit = LIMIT; // article per page
    $article = $this->Ile[0]['num']; // number of articles 

    if (isset($_GET['page'])){
        $page = $_GET['page'];
    } else {
        $page = 1;
    }

    $allpage = round($article/$limit);
    $from = $limit * ($page - 1);

    // $from send value to model and model return array with article

    foreach($this->Article as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<div style="float:left;width:660px;"><hr/><br/><p><span class="strong" style="color:#CC0000;">';
        echo $value['title'];
        echo '</span></p><br/><p>';
        echo $value['content'];
        echo '</p><div style="height:130px;">';
        echo $value['photo'];
        echo '</div></div>';
    }                   
    echo '<hr/>';
    echo '<div style="width: 660px; position: relative; pointer-events: none; text-align: center; top: 14px;">'.$page.' z '.$allpage.'</div>';

    if ($page == 1 && $page < $allpage)
    {
        echo '<a href="news?page='.($page+1).'" style="float: right;">STARSZE >></a>';
    }
    elseif ($page >= $allpage)
    {
        echo '<a href="news?page='.($page-1).'" style="float: left;"><< NOWSZE</a>';
    } else {
        echo '<a href="news?page='.($page-1).'" style="float: left;"><< NOWSZE</a>';
        echo '<a href="news?page='.($page+1).'" style="float: right;">STARSZE >></a>';
    }
?>
```

news.php

```
 class News extends Controller {

   function __construct() 
   {
     parent::__construct();
   }

   function index() 
   {
     $this->view->title = 'News';
     $this->view->Ile = $this->model->Ile();
     $this->view->Article = $this->model->Article();
     // I can put some value in ...->Article(0); and it works, but how connect in index.php

     $this->view->render('header');
     $this->view->render('news/index');
     $this->view->render('footer');
   }

 }
```

news_model.php

```
<?php

  class News_Model extends Model
  {
    public function __construct()
    {
      parent::__construct();
    }

    public function Ile()
    {
      return $this->db->select('SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM `articles`');
    }

    public function Article($from)
    {
      return $this->db->select('SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY `newsid` DESC LIMIT  '.$from.', '.LIMIT.'');
    }

  }
```

Regards,
 Thomas

Comment: You could either: Use the page URL to send the variable, make it global(although that would be somewhat of bad idea) or use $_SESSION. That's the first things that come to mind.

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC architecture. Just because you start referring to your table abstraction as "model" does not make it MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do this in your controller not in view :

**Controller :**

```
$limit = LIMIT; // article per page
$article = $this->view->Ile[0]['num']; // number of articles 

if (isset($_GET['page'])){
    $page = $_GET['page'];
} else {
    $page = 1;
}

$allpage = round($article/$limit);
$from = $limit * ($page - 1);
$this->view->Article = $this->model->Article($form); // This is how you can pass $form to model
```

And then you can assign This variable to your view like :

```
$this->view->page = $page
$this->view->allpage = $allpage
```

Now in view you can use $this->page instead of $page, same for $allpage

Hope it helps